# A generic class or methods to use with Linq to SQL with Stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I am new to Linq and previously have been using Ado.net classes.

I want to use Linq-to-SQL with stored procedures. can you please share code (or link of code) of a generic class to call different stored procedures. I dont want to make separate DAL classes/ methods for every database entity.

Thanks

Comment: You can add stored procedures to a DataContext as methods if you like.  You probably shouldn't use L2S if you don't want to directly represent your database entities and their relationships in code.  That's kind of the point of L2S.  What are you hoping to gain from using it?

Comment: Thanks @Pete M,

Rapid development as I will need to write least in DAL (I will generte SP as well) with performance better then Linq to SQL quries.
Yet performance will not better then ado.net but it will better then Linq to SQL quries. Whats your opinion ?

Comment: Have you measured it first? for many simple CRUD operations (typical in a generic repository layer) it will be about as fast either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of generics, you would presumably be limited to basic CRUD operations. In which case, you should be able to to use the *table*:

```
        DataContext ctx;
        var table = ctx.GetTable<Foo>();
        table.InsertOnSubmit(newObject);
        table.DeleteOnSubmit(oldObject);
```

(and update should work for entities that have been changed, using the SPROC that you have specified for updates).

the `SubmitChanges` will then use the correct sprocs automatically (you can specify a SPROC for insert, update and delete in the designer or the DBML. The tricky bit is the *get*. That is not exposed directly on the ctx... The only suggestion I have their is a name-based pattern on the data-context and reflection? So maybe a `GetFoo` method for getting a `Foo`.

Another approach, of course, is to implement multiple generic interfaces, i.e.

```
partial class MyDataContext : IFetch<Foo>, IFetch<Bar>
{
     Foo IFetch<Foo> Get(int key) { .. call get method on ctx ..}
     Bar IFetch<Bar> Get(int key) { .. call get method on ctx ..}
}
interface IFetch<T>
{
     T Get(int key);
}
```

(which extends the data-context)

Then you could cast the data-context:

```
var fetch = ctx as IFetch<T>();
return fetch.Get(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use such stored procedures for [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) purposes you can, in the edmx file (the one that holds the entities of the DB), right click the class you would like to perform the action on and select `Stored Procedure Mapping`. In there you'll find a list of the actions you can perform on such object.

P.S.: you also have to import the stored procedures from the DB when creating the models.

Comment: tags, title and qustion-body state LINQ-to-SQL, so we're talking DBML, not EDMX; different model.